# What is the phrase ending in "game" that means a fool's errand?

Tags: phrases

I am trying to remember the phrase that describes a particular kind of folly - trying to "beat the house", or willingness to play a rigged game.  As I recall it has the form of "a fool's errand" - that is, the game is referred to as belonging to the person who is silly enough to play it.  I'd appreciate knowing the origin of the phrase, too.

Comment: Speaking of which, you just lost [The Game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Game_(mind_game)).

Comment: @advs89: So did you. :P

Answer (score 4):

A little reflection brought to mind the phrase I was seeking: [A Mug's Game](http://wordsmith.org/words/mugs_game.html).  Originated [1910](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mug%27s+game?show=0&t=1298998690).

Comment: Aw, man, I knew that one.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "it is a fool's game" seems common and idiomatic enough.